# Getting error "not defined" for function called inside function

Tags: javascript, function, web, webpack, babeljs

I have a class and in that class, it has two functions and one static function. In the first function called `requestMovie()` I want to fetch data from API, then the second function is used to generate the URL called `generateUrl()`, and in the third function called `searchMovie()` I want to call the `generateUrl()` and `requestMovie()` functions but an error occurs that says the function is not defined

```
const MOVIE_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/';
const API_KEY = '####';


class ApiTransactions {

    requestMovies(url, onComplete, onError){
        return fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(onComplete)
        .catch(onError);
    }

    generateUrl(path){
        const url = `${MOVIE_ENDPOINT}${path}?api_key=${API_KEY}`;
        return url;
    }

    static searchMovie(keyword){
        const url = generateUrl('search/movie') + '&query=' + keyword;
        requestMovies(url,renderResult, fallbackResult);
    }
}

export default ApiTransactions;
```

and this error occurs saying:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQxn7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all `requestMovies` is an instance method and it should be referenced like `this.requestMovies()`, second since this is an instance method it can not be called from a static method, and so the method `searchMovie` can not be a static method.